# Запрос на вывод терминов из одной и той же таблицы по условию

Tags: php, sql

Как вывести коды уже переведенных терминов других языков которых нет на выбранном языке, чтобы показать какие коды терминов еще не переведены на данный язык?

Таблица терминов выглядит так

- id code text langCode
- 1 home Главная страница ru
- 2 home Home en

Например, при нажатии на добавление нового термина я могу видеть таблицу тех терминов которые у меня еще не переведены на русский язык

```
<?php
      $counterForTerms = 1;
      $termsWithLang = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT t1.code FROM terms AS t1 WHERE t1.code!=(SELECT t2.code FROM terms AS t2 WHERE langCode!='$ln' )");

      while($oneWithLangTerms=mysqli_fetch_assoc($termsWithLang)){
        echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$counterForTerms.'</td>
        <td>'.$oneWithLangTerms['code'].'</td>
        </tr>';
        $counterForTerms++;
      }
?>
```

[image: Модальное окно добавление термина]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выполнить ваш запрос, то получим ошибку:

> #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи

В этом случае для отрицания: `!=` (не равно) нужно использовать `NOT IN (...)` (не в списке).

Но так вы не получите ожидаемого результата. Потому что в подзапросе нужно выбрать `code` для которых уже есть переводы для выбранного `langCode`. Для понимания лучше разбить на два запроса.

---

Первый запрос. Выбираем переводы, для запрашиваемого языка `ru`:

```sql
SELECT `terms`.`code` FROM `terms` WHERE `langCode` = 'ru'
```

Второй запрос. Выбираем переводы, `code` которых нет в списке из первого запроса:

```sql
SELECT `terms`.`code` FROM `terms` WHERE `terms`.`code` NOT IN (...)
```

---

Но при такой выборке вы получите дубликаты `code`. Можно использовать один из вариантов.

Команда `DISTINCT` выбирает только уникальные значения, отсеивая дубли.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `terms`.`code` FROM `terms` WHERE `terms`.`code` NOT IN (...)
```

Команда `GROUP BY` группирует результаты.

```sql
SELECT `terms`.`code` FROM `terms` WHERE `terms`.`code` NOT IN (...) GROUP BY `terms`.`code`
```